# when ringer mode is changed to normal stop service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

when ringer mode is changed to normal how to do i stop my applications service.
Im new to android programming, confused and just need quick example. I have seen other info online but could not make any sense of it.

Comment: `audioManager.getStreamVolume(2);` this will return the value of ringer range `0-7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario you need to monitor the system event for ringer mode change. In android platform there is an application component called broadcast receiver

1. You need to create a new class subclassing [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and register it through xml declaration or program code.
2. Assign android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED action to its intent filter
3. Your BroadcastReceiver [onReceive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) method will be called with an intent as a parameter when the ringer mode is changed.
4. Check current ringer mode by looking into the received intent extra with [EXTRA_RINGER_MODE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#EXTRA_RINGER_MODE). And compare the value with [RINGER_MODE_NORMAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
5. Issue an intent to [context.stopService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) to stop your running service if the condition in point 4 satisfied

Comment: how do i unregister a broadcast receiver once the Ringer Mode has been set to normal. i.e once the Ringer Mode has been set to normal , my service stops by context.stopService() but I also have a class that uses a broadcast receiver I want to unregister it and stop listening for texts once the Ringer mode is set to normal

Comment: So you want your broadcast receiver one time only, is that what you mean? I my point of view, you can just leave it there. Even the broadcast receiver being called twice, stopping a stopped service won't have much negative impact.

[Context.unregisterReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29) can do what you want